# Definition Fixed Element

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

I am looking for the definition of a "fixed element".  The context is 
"Let G be a group and let a be one fixed element of $G$.  Show that $H_a = \{x \in G | xa=ax \}$ is a subgroup of $G$."
Thanks.

Comment: It means that in what follows, $a$ will be held constant. It could just as well have been stated as "let $a$ be an element of $G$".

Comment: You probably have a group with a group *action*? Or another group acting upon G?

Comment: This is not the whole context. Please explain the whole context, otherwise the question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that we consider a given element of $G$ and call it $a$.
$a$ remains fixed means that when we talk about $a$ we talk about
the same element we always referred to with the name $a$.

Now, the question asks you that given some $a\in G$ show that the
set of element in $G$ which commutes with $G$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I would leave it for you to verify, but for example note that $1\in H_{a}$
since $1\cdot a=a\cdot1$